# How to move a Facebook friend to a list quickly?

Tags: facebook, friend-list

I open the homepage of a friend (their facebook home page), like it, and want to add that friend to my list, say "Favourite", but not sure how to do it quickly.

At the moment, I got to go to the Friend List manager of my own account, choose a list, and add the frined to that list - which is very annoying.

How are you adding friend to list quickly? Please share :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Facebook chat, next to each list you can find a **modify** link. Click on it and select your friend. Easier i think ;)

Comment: Of course, this requires the friend being online when you want to do this.

Comment: no, it doesnt requires the friend being online.

Comment: D'oh, sorry.  I totally misread your post.  In other news, you can also drag and drop your online friends around to place them in another list.  I somehow managed to interpret your post like that.

Comment: The link says **edit** for me.

Comment: sorry i dont have access to Facebook ^^ the link is **edit** not **modify**

Comment: Sorry, how do you see lists in Facebook chat?